# NonType to tensor in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, opencv

I am using the `cv2.imread()` to open a png image in order to test my model for handwritten classification. I am working on Colab and after i mount the drive and open the image I check the type of the img:

```
type(img)
```

The answear is 'NonType', so when I am trying to convert it to tensor I get an error:

```
> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported
> object type NoneType).
```

Then i converted the NonType object to numpy.ndarray and then to tensor `tf.convert_to_tensor()` but I still get the same error, why is that and how should I open and use images in colab so as I can make the predictions ?

Answer (score 0):

When `cv2.imread()` fails to load an image (mostly likely, because the path you passed it doesn't correspond to a file), it returns `None`. Always check the return value before proceeding, as errors can sometimes seem mysterious.